# How to make resizable text in an item in a list in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm creating a cell which has multiple text and an image in it. I want one text to resize itself and its cell, but how to do it?

I tried using .fixedSize() and some UILabel calculation but I could fix it.

Navigation Button which is also a cell in the list:

```swift
NavigationButton(destination: ..., isDetail: true, label: {
                    Cell(model: rowModel)
                })
```

```swift
struct Cell: View {
    var model: OfferModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "camera").frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(model.name)
                        .font(.caption)
                        .textContentType(.name)
                    Text(self.model.text)
                        .lineLimit(3)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .font(.title)
                }
                Spacer()
                OfferPriceView(model: model, alignment: .trailing)
            }
            OfferDetailInformationView(key: "Street", value: model.adress, style: .streetAddressLine1)
            OfferDetailInformationView(key: "City", value: model.city, style: .addressCity)
            OfferDetailInformationView(key: "Country", value: model.country, style: .countryName)
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct OfferDetailInformationView: View {
    var key: String
    var value: String
    var style: UITextContentType?

    init(key: String, value: String, style: UITextContentType? = nil) {
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.style = style
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(key):").bold()
            Text(value)
            .textContentType(style)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct OfferPriceView : View {
    let model: OfferModel
    let alignment: HorizontalAlignment

    init(model: OfferModel = .example, alignment: HorizontalAlignment = .center) {
        self.model = model
        self.alignment = alignment
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: alignment) {
            Text("\(String(format: "%.2f", model.cost))\(model.currency)").bold().color(.red)
            Text(model.paymentRate).color(.red)
        }
    }
}
```

I would like the Text with model.text to be expanded vertically if the text doesn't fit in a single line. For now it just clips the tex in one line.

The view structure is as follows:

- Content View:

  - List:

    - Navigation Button:

      - Vertical Stack:

        - Horizontal Stack:

          - Image
          - Vertical Stack:

            - Text(model.name)
            - Text(model.text)
          - Spacer
          - Vertical Stack (inside OfferPriceView):

            - Text
            - Text
        - Horizontal Stack (OfferDetailInformationView)

          - Text(currency)
          - Text(payment)
          - Spacer

Comment: post `OfferDetailInformationView` ,  `OfferPriceView`

Comment: Where is your list?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Edited to add clarification of what is in the list. The Navigation Button is in the list.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Text("Hello")
.font(.largeTitle)
.minimumScaleFactor(0.3)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.lineLimit` modifier is the one that controls `Text` height based on their content.

So if you want to have an unlimited lines of text (should be fit in screen or you must use `ScrollView`), you should use this:

```
.lineLimit(nil)
```

**UPDATE**

Tested in Xcode 11 Beta 7 and `nil` works as expected to be no limit. But if `nil` is not acceptable (like it wasn't on earlier versions), so set it to a large integer number:

```
.lineLimit(Int.max)
```

**Keep in mind** The second option is just a workaround till `SwiftUI` reaches it first release version.

Comment: Oh boy I tried so many options with line limit and it isn’t working, still one line...

Comment: Why and how? Maybe it's not the code. Can you share the simple working project?

Comment: I've added the View hierarchy, that might help

Answer (score 0):

You can use lineLimit(nil) to make text multiline

```
    Text(repo.description)
                .font(.subheadline)
                .lineLimit(nil)
```

Comment: note that lineLimit(nil) not working atm in the betas

Comment: It works, for me on the latest beta, maybe there is some case when it is not working?

Comment: on iPhone XS it doesn't expand the lines

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Xcode 11.1 GM Seeds, If you don't give any `lineLimit` modifier to text, then `Text` will set line limit to infinite as per its text string content.

**Generated this:**

[image]

**By Using this Code:** 
[image]